# Add change text on click with existing onclick button in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image]

I want to change the text when the user clicks a link, but I have an existing `onclick` jQuery function. I'm planning on adding the text change onto it.
What it does is when the user clicks on the color, the image changes. I wanted to add the name of the image too.

Here's the format of code.

```
<div class = "car-img-quote col-md-6" >
    <div class="img animation" data-animation ="fadeIn"><img id="image" src="vios-color/vios_AJM.jpg" alt="" ></div>
        <div class = "thumb-img-quote">
            <div class = "thumb-container">
                <div class="thumb" id = "thumb">
                    <span data-src="vios-color/vios_AJM.jpg"><a href="#?" class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-Alumina-Jade.png">  </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_B.jpg"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Black.png"> </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_BRM.jpg"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Black-Red.png"> </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_BMM.jpg"><a href="#?"class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-Blue-Metal.png"></a></span>
                    <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_FW.jpg"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Freedom-White.png"> </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_OM.jpg"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Orange-Metal.png"> </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_RMM.jpg"><a href="#?"class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-Red-Metal.png">  </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_SM.jpg"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="../../thumb/th-Silver-Metal.png">  </a></span>
                    <span  data-src="vios-color/vios_WP.jpg"><a href="#?"class = "label" ><img src="../../thumb/th-White-Pearl.png"> </a></span>
                </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery. I just don't know where to add it though, since I'm still learning the language.

```
$('.thumb span').each(function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    var src = _this.data("src");
    _this.find('a').click(function(){
        $("#image").show( function() {
            $(".img img").attr("src", src);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you describe a little bit more clear what you want to achieve ? You can have multiple on clicks and with classes you can bind the event to specific elements,

Comment: i'll add some pics to make it clear.

Comment: add the image url to respective data-src... & make a working html code on snippet

Comment: So, where do you get the name of the color? or how do you know the name of that color?

Comment: @Haze i haven't add it . that's what i'm thinking on where should i stick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same approach that you are using to store and pick image src values. You can take one more data attribute in your thumb elements and keep respective titles in these.

Now, on click you can pick the text similar to picking the src and update it using `text` method of jQuery.

```js
$('.thumb span').each(function(){
  var _this = $(this);
  var src = _this.data("src");
  var text = _this.data("caption");
  _this.find('a').click(function(){
     $("#image").show( function() {
    $(".img img").attr("src", src);
    $("#caption").text(text);
     });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "car-img-quote col-md-6" >
                    <div class="img animation" data-animation ="fadeIn"><img id="image" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/fashion" alt="" >
                    <div id="caption">Fashion</div></div>
              <div class = "thumb-img-quote">
                <div class = "thumb-container">

                    <div class="thumb" id = "thumb">


                        <span data-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/fashion" data-caption="Fashion"><a href="#?" class = "label" ><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/fashion">  </a></span>
                        <span  data-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people" data-caption="People"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people"> </a></span>
                        <span  data-src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food" data-caption="Food"><a href="#?" class = "label"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/food"> </a></span>
                     </div>
                       <div class="clear"></div>
                 </div>
            </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: RIGHT ON THE MONEY!. Thank you!

Comment: how do i style the text?

Comment: You can use css to style the text in any way you want. It's just a simple div element or if you want you can use any other element to hold the text.

Answer (score 0):

So, you wanted to change the source of *image* with **id** `image` at the top once you click on any span tags at the bottom.

Try this simple approach

```
$( '.thumb span a img' ).each(function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
  $( "#image" ).show();
  $( "#image" ).attr( "src", $( this ).closest( "span" ).attr( "data-src" ) );
});
```

Comment: what i want is to change the text too. the img is working alright.

Comment: @jmv add text to what?

Comment: added the pic for clear explanation. i want the text change too. so that when the user click the color. the name of the color and the image will change too

Comment: @jmv this is fine, but to which element text should be added to?

Comment: @jmv also, from where should this text (color name) be fetched from?

Comment: yea that's what im thinking . on where should i add it. since the img and the color img are the one that's changing

Answer (score 0):

You can add the color name in span data attribute just like the image source.

```
<span data-src="vios-color/vios_AJM.jpg" data-title="your-color">
 <a href="#?" class = "label" >
     <img src="../../thumb/th-Alumina-Jade.png">
 </a> 
</span>
```

and add a `<p>` below your image.

```
<div class="img animation" data-animation ="fadeIn">
  <img id="image" src="vios-color/vios_AJM.jpg" alt="" > 
  <p clas="title"></p>
</div>
```

and just like replacing your image source, you can replace the text.

```
$("p.title").html(_this.data("title"));
```